# Short story about fried dinosaur being delicious

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

This was an odd one, I read a while ago in a large collection.

The basic plot was that some time in the past the ability to open a portal through time was created.
But the only thing that came of it was that a couple of Velociraptors made it through to the modern day.
They were captured and eventually started breeding, and at some point people were like *"Lets fry them up KFC style"*, and it was the most delicious food ever.

I think the whole story was written as obituary, or some other reflection on the recently deceased.
Something like *"I looked out at the tomb of my father: inventor, philanthropists and hero. Perhaps his greatest discovery was the Velociraptor, the most delectable fried creature ever to exist."*

I think it was written by someone quite notable, Asimov, Silverberg, or someone else of that era. But I could be wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### ["A Statue for Father"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?68271) (1959) by Isaac Asimov

It was first published in [*Satellite Science Fiction*, February 1959](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?196765) and then later [*Buy Jupiter and Other Stories*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?262633) (1975) which is a larger collection so probably where you read it.

> A theoretical physicist and his son work on the theory of time travel, and experiment with a method of reaching back into time and retrieving objects (as also occurs in "The Ugly Little Boy" and "Button, Button").
>
> More by serendipity than design, they manage to retrieve a nest of dinosaur eggs which in due course hatch. They keep on working but are unable to repeat the experiment. In the meantime, the dinosaurs grow and are kept as pets. But when one of them accidentally gets electrocuted, they can't resist tasting the flesh beneath the scales and find that it tastes delicious.
>
> The two men decide to raise the dinosaurs to be killed for food and open the first of a successful chain of restaurants dedicated to serving "dinachicken.".
>
> The ironic twist of the title is that the physicist is remembered not for his scientific achievements, but for his culinary discovery.
>
> <sub>[Wikipedia, A Statue for Father](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Statue_for_Father)</sub>

Comment: So THAT’S where dinonuggets come from!

Comment: yes, that was it. I think must have read it in "The Complete Stories Volume 2"
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Complete_Stories_(Asimov)#Volume_2